# Optimization for this SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a WordPress site and I make a query to get all the users that have a specific capability/range. From the list, I get a "meta_value" that has a timestamp, and then I check if it is less than the current time (expired)

```
$sql = "SELECT user_id
FROM  `wp_usermeta` 
WHERE  `meta_key` =  'wp_capabilities'
AND  `meta_value` LIKE  '%\"premium\"%'";

$query = mysqli_query($cn, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    $user_id = $row["user_id"];

    $sql = "SELECT meta_value
    FROM  `wp_usermeta` 
    WHERE  `meta_key` = '_expire_user_date'
    AND user_id = '$user_id'";

    $query_time = mysqli_query($cn, $sql);
    $rows_query_time = mysqli_fetch_array($query_time);
    $expire_user_date = $rows_query_time["meta_value"];

    $now = time();

    if ($expire_user_date && $now > $expire_user_date)
    {
        echo $user_id." expired<br>";
    }
}
```

It's possible to use JOIN or something to optimize the query?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking for the users who are expired and has particular capabilities?

Comment: Hello. Yes, who are expired and has the particulap capability "premium".

Comment: You should be using prepared statements, otherwise your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try self join query on `usermeta` table in WordPress**

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_usermeta` um1 join `wp_usermeta` um2 
ON um1.user_id = um2.user_id 
AND um1.meta_key =  'wp_capabilities' 
AND um1.meta_value LIKE '%premium%' 
AND  `um2`.`meta_key` = '_expire_user_date
```

Comment: Thanks, my final query is: SELECT um2.meta_value FROM wp_usermeta um1 JOIN wp_usermeta um2 ON um1.user_id = um2.user_id AND um1.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' AND um1.meta_value LIKE '%premium%' AND um2.meta_key = '_expire_user_date' so it helps me to check the time of each row

Answer (score 0):

`Left Join` or `subquery` will work. I think `Left Join` will be optimal one

```
"SELECT umeta.user_id, 
         exmeta.meta_value as meta_value
     FROM  `wp_usermeta` AS umeta 
     LEFT JOIN `wp_usermeta` AS exmeta
        ON umeta.user_id = exmeta.user_id
        WHERE  umeta.`meta_key` =  'wp_capabilities'
            AND  umeta.`meta_value` LIKE  '%\"premium\"%'
            AND  exmeta.`meta_key` = '_expire_user_date'

";
```

But easiest one is `subquery` which is little bit slower than left join

```
"SELECT user_id, 
        (SELECT meta_value
             FROM `wp_usermeta` 
                 WHERE user_id = umeta.user_id
                       AND `meta_key` = '_expire_user_date' 
                 LIMIT 1
        ) as meta_value
FROM  `wp_usermeta` AS umeta 
WHERE  `meta_key` =  'wp_capabilities'
AND  `meta_value` LIKE  '%\"premium\"%'";
```

Comment: Hello! The query returns me "Column 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous", btw thanks for reply :-)

Comment: @JasonDerek exactly thanks , I updated my answer. Thanks for correction. LEFT JOIN is fastest one.

Answer (score -1):

It's better to let the database manage the filtering. 
Try something like this:

```
"SELECT user_id
FROM  `wp_usermeta` 
WHERE  `meta_key` =  'wp_capabilities'
AND  `meta_value` LIKE  '%\"premium\"%'"
AND 'timestamp_column' > NOW()
```

Than you get all the "expired" rows.

Comment: Hello! In this case, the timestamp is not within a column. Thanks for reply